# Ansible - Jeniks pipeline too slow to copy files to network location

Tags: jenkins, ansible

Any idea  / suggest to speed up automatic deployment of files on a network location, I have 200 MB folder containing multiple files and sub folder. However, when I try to deploy using pipeline, it is talking around 4 hrs to deploy.

Any suggestions to improve performance please?

Pipeline steps:

1. Zip files on a windows server (< 5 mins)
2. Move .zip file to destination directory (around 10-12 mins)
3. Unzip on destination ( takes around 3.5 to 4 hrs)

My script below

```
- name: "Download maven artifact {{ group_id }}:{{ artifact }}:{{ version }}"
  win_get_url:
    url:  "{{ nexus_repository_url }}&g={{ group_id }}&a={{ artifact }}&v={{ version }}&c={{ classifier }}&p={{ packformat }}"
    dest: "{{ staging }}\\{{ artifact }}-{{ version }}.zip"
    username: "{{ lookup('env', 'DSNEXUS_USERNAME') }}"
    password: "{{ lookup('env', 'DSNEXUS_PASSWORD') }}"
    validate_certs: no
    when: nexusSource
```

```
- name: Find directories to deploy
  win_find:
    paths: "{{ staging }}"
    file_type: directory
    register: folders_to_copy
```

```
- name: Create the target Folder at NAS root
  win_file:
    path: "{{ root }}\\{{ target_folder }}"
    state: directory
```

```
- name : Perform deployment here.
  win_copy:
    remote_src: yes
    src:  "{{ staging }}\\{{ artifact }}-{{ version }}.zip"
    dest: "{{ root }}\\{{ target_folder }}\\{{ artifact }}-{{ version }}.zip"
```

```
- name : unzip here on destination.
  win_unzip:
    remote_src: yes
    src: "{{ root }}\\{{ target_folder }}\\{{ artifact }}-{{ version }}.zip"
    dest: "{{ root }}\\{{ target_folder }}"
```

Comment: This looks more like an ansible question. Unzip a file over the network is never a good idea. Try to find another solution for this. Can you run the unzip on the target machine?

Comment: Due to access restriction wont be able to run unzip on target location. I tried reversing logic , unzip and deploy files - this is too slow as well.